# Recourse for prosecution whose witness suddenly changes their story on the stand

Tags: rules-of-court, trial, witnesses, criminal-procedure, perjury

Say prosecution has a witness who saw the defendant do the crime and is happy to testify it on the stand.

But when they take the stand, they suddenly surprise the prosecution by saying they did not see anything (thereby effectively commiting perjury). They may do it because the defendant has threatened them, or offered money, or whatever. A famous (though not real) example is Frank Pentangeli suddenly saying at the trial that he knows nothing about Michael Corleone's family (crime organization) in *The Godfather Part II*:

[image]

In modern criminal courts, what can the prosecution do to fix that? Can they ask the court to adjourn the trial, talk some sense into the witness and have them on the stand again to tell the truth? If so, can the prosecution just carry on with other witnesses and simply bring the liar on the stand again another day, or does it necessarily need to advise the court immediately of what has happened and request an adjournment?

Comment: isn't that why you have a deposition of the witness first?!

Comment: @Trish That may be an answer. I don't know.

Comment: Presumably they could find out if the sudden change was due to threats. At which point they can discuss witness protection in return for testimony about the threats.

Comment: The outcome would probably be different in the U.S. (which has very strong double jeopardy protections) from other common law jurisdictions (which have more exceptions).

Comment: @Trish depositions aren't very common in criminal practice when the witness has already provided a statement (not necessarily recorded or in writing) to law enforcement and there is no reason in advance to suspect a change in story.

Comment: @ohwilleke Couldn't that statement be used as something akin to the replacement for the deposition transcript in that case? Best if it is in writing, but... yea, sometimes it is not.

Comment: @Trish Usually yes, as explained in my answer.

Comment: Incidentally, the *Godfather* scene was testimony before a Congressional committee, not a trial court.

Comment: @PaulJohnson That's an option. The question is more about tactics/practicalities of that. Ask for a recess immediately (and thereby postpone testimony from other witnesses in prosecution's favor)? Or just carry on, have other witnesses testify and later put the liar witness on the stand again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In U.S. practice, double jeopardy protections attach once the jury is seated and this scenario contemplates the change in position arising at trial.

A mistrial could be called, or a continuance obtained, if the defendant suddenly claimed an alibi defense, since that amounts of a defendant waiver of double jeopardy protections. But without proof that the witness was tampered with, obtained at the last moment, it can be difficult or impossible to get proof of tampering or to contradict the story with other evidence to undermine the credibility of the witness.

The prosecution would probably request a recess in the trial to regroup and try to admit evidence that the testimony changing witness made a prior inconsistent statement to impeach the testimony of that witness, from whomever that witness told the first time (probably a law enforcement officer). But this is still far less convincing to a jury than an affirmative statement from a witnesses about a key fact.

If the prosecution could find evidence of defense side tampering and present it to the judge in the hours or small number of days before the trial ends, it might be able to get a mistrial declared. But it is much harder to get a mistrial for witness tampering when the witness shows up and testifies contrary to prosecution expectations than it is when the witness is, for example, killed or kidnapped and doesn't appear to testify at trial at all.

But if evidence of neither type could be obtained before the jury was sent to deliberate and evidence was closed, and the jury then acquitted the defendant, it would be very hard for the prosecution to change this result. Perhaps not completely impossible, but very nearly so.

The witness could be (and in this circumstance, despite the extreme rarity of perjury prosecutions, probably would be) prosecuted for perjury, but that wouldn't change the acquittal.

If a link to the defendant could be found, the defendant could also be prosecuted for witness tampering or obstruction of justice or something similar. But that is hard to prove (and the witness would probably have to be convicted or provided with use immunity for his testimony) to do so.

In English criminal law practice, in contrast, the likelihood of having the verdict of acquittal set aside and getting a new trial would be much greater (and the likelihood of getting a recess mid-trial would be greater in far more common bench trials in lower level criminal cases), but it would still be a serious burden for the prosecution that it might not be able to overcome.

Lawyers aren't entitled to expect that witnesses will testify exactly the way that they discussed things with the lawyers before trial, and this can be explained away with a variety of excuses that are usually true ("after thinking it over after meeting with you, I realized that I was confused and getting it wrong"), but are sometimes a cover for a change of story that is not sincere.

I've had similar things happen a few times in civil litigation and there is only so much you can do about it.

Comment: "_regroup and try to admit evidence that the testimony changing witness made a prior inconsistent statement to impeach the testimony of that witness_" the previous statement would not have been made under oath. It would have been just an interview. Would that therefore ever have any weight against what they say on the stand?

Comment: @Greendrake Sure. Nobody, least of all jurors, believe that people are more likely to be truthful testifying on the stand in court under oath than they are in an interview out of court. It is a legal fiction. The opposite is almost always true.

Comment: What people believe doesn't matter as much as what the procedure finds, does it? Everyone could be sure that the defendant is guilty, but if no sufficient evidence gets delivered on the stand, the jury/judge will acquit them.

Comment: @Greendrake If a witness under oath offers up an unsworn prior inconsistent statement that gets in the record, the judge and jury and entitled to find that more credible than the sworn statement made in court. Credibility is the province of the fact finder.

Comment: Sorry I am getting confused with the difference between "under oath" and "sworn" that you mean. As I understand, whatever the witness tells outside of the courtroom (e.g. police interview) is neither sworn nor under oath (if there is any difference at all). Am I getting it wrong? If you imply that the witness swears any statements before they get on the stand, that's not a premise of the question: I assume that the witness simply gives interview to the police/prosecution, promises to say the same on the stand but does not swear the interview statements.

Comment: @Greendrake I am saying that the out of court state is not made under oath but that person recounting the out of court statement in the courtroom is under oath. Such a statement is frequently admissible as evidence. The fact that someone says something to a cop outside the courtroom without being under oath doesn't make the out of court statement not admissible as evidence. It might be hearsay but there are many exceptions to the hearsay rule, some of which would probably apply in this example.

Comment: If you've got evidence for witness tampering, you might not need the mistrial. The normal process of impeach the witness should be capable of bringing that evidence to light, and it won't look good for the defendant.