# If a witness for the prosecution recants on the stand because induced by the defense, what can the prosecution do to make up for it?

Tags: witnesses, perjury, impeachment

I'll try to summarize my details here. The lawyer is the only witness to what the other witness said. So, unless the lawyer takes the stand, the other witness cannot be contradicted, especially is if (s)he was alone, did not sign any written statement, and there is no tape recording or video to impeach him/her. The client on trial would be declared not guilty, and the witness would be guilty only of perjury. To answer my own question, maybe the witness must be considered hostile and hope to catch him/her in a mistake? In any way, to me this is a perfectly legal strategy, and a valid witness on the stand, but I want to hear your expert opinion on this.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to follow your question. Are you asking how a defense lawyer can suborn perjury to get his client acquitted.

Comment: The defense can call their own witness, they don't have to make the prosecution do it.  A single witness may or may not affect the outcome of a case.  People on both sides lie all the time.  It is up to the jury to decide on the merit of testimony.

Comment: Sounds like a potentially good question, but horribly formulated. −1.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it sounds like you think it is somehow harder for the prosecution to challenge the credibility of their own witness, than to do so for an opposing witness.  Therefore, if there is a witness with testimony favorable to the defense but poor credibility, you think the defense would be better off if they can convince the prosecution to call that witness, than for the defense to call that witness themselves.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Modified the title, I hope it's more clear. Also, I changed the body of text.

Comment: What admissible evidence is there that the defence induced the witness? Could they not have changed their account without any external influence?

Comment: If I didn't phrase it this way, it would be a question identical to this one: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/58953/recourse-for-prosecution-whose-witness-suddenly-changes-their-story-on-the-stand

Answer (score 1):

### The prosecution decides who to call as prosecution witnesses

Similarly, the defence decides who to call as defence witnesses.

If a party decides that a particular witness’ testimony is of little or no probative value, they don’t introduce it.